# DynamicRadio Button 

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using C# in VS2005. For my application I need to create four radio buttons. My form looks like:

```
A(Radio Button)  
B(Radio Button)
C(Radio Button)
D(Radio Button)
```

---

```
Submit (Button)
```

When a user clicks the submit button I need to know which radio button is checked. How can I determine this?

Comment: added windows-forms tag; I answered with code for web, but then realized the question says windows.

Answer (score 1):

I would add all the radio buttons to a `List<RadioButton>` which would help you innumerate through them when the submit is checked to figure out which one is checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Checked` Property of a `RadioButton` to see if it is checked:

```
bool isChecked = radA.Checked;
```

I often use the following helper function to get exactly the `RadioButton` which is checked:

```
public RadioButton GetCheckedRadioButton(Control container)
{
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else if (container is RadioButton) {
        return GetCheckedRadioButton(container.Parent);
    }
    else {
        foreach (Control childControl in container.Controls) {
            if (childControl is RadioButton) {
                RadioButton radioBtn = (RadioButton) childControl;

                if (radioBtn.Checked) {
                    return radioBtn;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, you can simply call this function using one of your controls or it's container, and do a switch statement, as such:

```
switch(GetCheckedRadioButton(radA)) {
    case radA:
        // radA is checked
        break;
    case radB:
        // radB is checked
        break;
}
```

Personally, I find it less verbose than the usual:

```
if(radA.Checked) {
   //radA is checked
}
else if(radB.Checked) {
   //radB is checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that you will only need 4 RadioButtons, then I'd just write code similar to this.

```
if (Radio1.Checked) ...
if (Radio2.Checked) ...
if (Radio3.Checked) ...
...
```

If you know that only one of them can be checked at the same time (using a group box or some other mechanism) then you can optimise this by using "else if" instead.

However if there is a possibility that you will need more, this can get wasteful, so I agree with other answers, you should put them in a collection of your choice and use it to loop through them, to see which ones are checked.